# Return an array in Java within a function

Tags: java, arrays, return

I've written this code to problem from Leetcode in Java. Question 496 Next Greater Element I. Here I must return an array with its brackets, like output must be for example [-1,3,-1]. I cannot print it, but only return. How to do it?

Link for question from Leetcode
https://leetcode.com/problems/next-greater-element-i/description/?envType=study-plan&id=programming-skills-i

```
public int[] nextGreaterElement(int[] nums1, int[] nums2) {
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int i = 0;i<nums1.length;i++){
        for (int j = 0;j<nums2.length;j++){
            if (nums1[i] == nums2[j]){
                try{
                    if(nums1[i] < nums2[j+1]){
                        list.add(nums2[j+1]);

                    }else{
                        list.add(-1);
                    }
                }catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e){
                    list.add(-1);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    int[] array = list.stream().mapToInt(i->i).toArray();
    for (int i = 0; i<array.length;i++){
        System.out.println(array[i]);
    }
    return new int[]{}array; // this is error (should return [-1,3,-1])
}
```

Comment: There's no such thing as "an array with its brackets". There's just an array. It sounds like you just need to replace the last part of your code with `return array;`

Comment: But it outputs like this `[I@5b480cf9`

Comment: @Abdumutalibov that is just the String representation of an `Integer[]`. It doesn't matter what it looks like when you print it, your task is to return it. Does it work when you submit the answer?

Comment: @f1sh Unfortunately no

Comment: More specifically, that's the String representation of an `int[]` (not an `Integer[]`). It seems like this is basically a failing on the part of Leetcode to produce readable output. We can't easily tell whether it's actually checking the output correctly and is only displaying poor diagnostics, or whether it's checking against the string representation.

Comment: @JonSkeet you are of course correct regarding the `int[]`, for `Integer` it would be `[Ljava.lang.Integer@abc123`. Did not mean to confuse anyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line `return new int[]{}array;` is not a statement.  You are trying to return a `new int[]`, which doesn't cause an error by itself, but adding the `array` after the `new int[]{}` does absolutely nothing and causes a compiler error.  Just return the array you created above it.

```java
    int[] array = list.stream().mapToInt(i->i).toArray();
    return array;
```

I tested your response:

```java
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
  {
    int[] nums1 = {4,1,2};
    int[] nums2 = {1,3,4,2};
    int[] expected = {-1,3,-1};

    var result = nextGreaterElement(nums1, nums2);

    if (Arrays.equals(expected, result)){
      System.out.println("They are the same");
    } else {
      System.out.println("They are different");
    }
  }
```

The output was `They are the same`.